# WebRTC - Find out MediaStreamTrack Type?

Tags: javascript, stream, webrtc, signaling

I want to find out if the VideoTrack contains a screenshare or webcam stream.
I can't find any attribute and also no fitting contraint I could [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/applyConstraints) to the track and read out later.

Someone knows a smart way to do that?

I want to avoid sending the streamId with the type over the dataChannel.

Thanks :)

EDIT1: So far no solution... so I have to send the streamType and StreamId over the datachannel

Answer (score 0):

The process works like this (using MediaStreamTrack as an example):

1. If needed, call `MediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()` to get the
   list of supported constraints, which tells you what constrainable
   properties the browser knows about. This isn't always necessary,
   since any that aren't known will simply be ignored when you specify
   them—but if you have any that you can't get by without, you can
   start by checking to be sure they're on the list.
2. Once the script knows whether the property or properties it wishes
   to use are supported, it can then check the capabilities of the API
   and its implementation by examining the object returned by the
   track's `getCapabilities()` method; this object lists each supported
   constraint and the values or range of values which are supported.
3. nally, the track's `applyConstraints()` method is called to configure
   the API as desired by specifying the values or ranges of values it
   wishes to use for any of the constrainable properties about which it
   has a preference.
4. The track's `getConstraints()` method returns the set of constraints
   passed into the most recent call to `applyConstraints()`. This may not
   represent the actual current state of the track, due to properties
   whose requested values had to be adjusted and because platform
   default values aren't represented. For a complete representation of
   the track's current configuration, use `getSettings()`.

In the Media Stream API, both MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack have constrainable properties.

Comment: ty, but I know that: "I can't find any attribute and also no fitting contraint I could apply to the track and read out later". There are not supported contrains/settings that would fit in chrome or ff I could add to my MediaStreamTrack